# WPF Datagrid and SQL Relational Data

Tags: sql, wpf, datagrid

I've got the following Problem: I've got 2 Datagrids bound to a Dataset via Collectionviewsource. The Dataset contains 2 Tables in relation with one another.

The first DG displays the parent data, the second displays the relational (dependent) data.

Now, originally I tried to travese the Rows shown in the second DG like I used to in WInForms with the DataGridView controls.

After a little research I figured that there is no row property in the DataGrid, as it only displays the data bound to it.

Now how do I access the data shown in the second datagrid so I could list the content in certain columns in a a listview?

thx

Max